# Parse config array of PFFile

Tags: parse-platform

Do you know if it's possible to store an array of PFFile in Parse Config ? I haven't found it on [Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#config/iOS).

I would like to store a background image & icon for each category in my app. At the moment I have 15 categories, and i would like to be able to add/remove/edit these images without having to change anything on my app.
So far, the only way i have found to do that is to create an array of string, which contains the keys to retrieve these PFFile.

Here is the code:

```
 NSArray *kCategories = [config objectForKey:@"Categories"];
 for (NSString *key in kCategories) {
     NSString *backgroundKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"background_%@", key];
     NSString *iconKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon_%@", key];
     PFFile *background = [config objectForKey:backgroundKey ];
     PFFile *icon = [config objectForKey:iconKey ];
     // Do something with it
 }
```

It works, but I still need to create 30 PFFile individually on my dashboard as I have 15 category (background+icon), which I think is it quite a dirty.

I'll be pleased to hear any suggestions.